# Minimum Number of Groups / Rows Algorithim

Tags: algorithms

I am pretty sure this simple problem has a proper name but I have no idea what it is.

I have a number of blocks of different widths (all same height).

I would like to stack these blocks horizontally such that the width of the row does not exceed a predefined Max Width constant. If at any moment placing a new block makes the width of the row exceeds the maximum, the block is removed and put on a new row.

Is there an algorithm for optimal stacking of the blocks such that the number of rows is minimum?

I was able to abstract this problem by saying that I have N different numbers and my objective would be to put these numbers in P groups such that the sum of any group does not exceed M (the maximum). The objective would be to have the minimum number of groups.

What is the name of this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: It's called "bin-packing", and there is an enormous literature about it.

Comment: Have you had a look?

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you for pointing out the correct name of the problem. This makes an excellent starting point.